# Ошибка с подключением OpenCV к проекту

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Пытаюсь подключить OpenCV библиотеки к проекту Visual Studio 2019, используя диспетчер пакетов NuGet. В ходе написания кода ошибки не возникают. Однако, когда пытаюсь скомпилировать код, возникают ошибки типа:

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ cvReleaseImage в функции main
```

Что делать в данной ситуации?

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "test.png" );                 // Получение имени изображения
    cvNamedWindow( "DisplayPicture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  // Создание окна
    cvShowImage( "DisplayPicture", img );                   // Показ изображения
    cvWaitKey( 0 );                                           // Ожидание
    cvReleaseImage( &img );                                 // Освобождение памяти из под изображения
    cvDestroyWindow( "DisplayPicture" );                    // Удаление окна
}
```

Comment: наверное  cvReleaseImage( img ).  Не знаком с этой функцией, но по логике она должна принимать указатель на IplImage , а не указатель на указатель

Comment: У меня подобные ошибки ко всем функциям, начинающимся на cv...

Comment: Ну погуглите, узнайте какая библиотека нужна, ознакомтесь с документацией. Лично я не пользуюсь  этими средствами, не смогу подсказать

Comment: Битности подключаемой бибилиотеки и проекта совпадают?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, да.

Comment: @qucals `VS19`, не умеет использовать `openCV`, которая лежит в `NuGet`. Скачайте с офф. сайта и не парьтесь. Я думаю настроить по интсрукции, вы сможете. В `NuGet-е` лежит версия, для `VS12`, `lib-ы` и так же `dll`.

Comment: @qucals, как пример ваш код в моей студии с установленой версией `openCV 2.4.13.6`, всё с компилировалось и запустилось.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKJGy.png

Comment: есть же отличные гайды как подключать ручками опенсв. А зачем вам vs если не секрет.

Comment: @jNX, Хм.. А что в VS такого?

Comment: visual studia же

Comment: @jNX, вы можете посоветовать другую среду разработки? (кроме Qt)

Comment: вы пользуетесь ради компилятора и сборщика ? Ну вы понимаете что вы можете в теории подключить библиотеки нужые и в vs но при помощи cmake. Просто пользуйтесь qtcreator совместно с cmake. Не обязательно же использовать сам qt